# abusing convergence in distribution notation

Tags: distributions, convergence, notation

If I have $\sqrt{n} (X_n - c) \xrightarrow[]{d} N(0,v) $ does it make any sense at all to say this implies that $X_n  \xrightarrow[]{d} N(c, \frac{v}{n})$.

If not, what is the accurate way/notation that allows me to express the above?

Comment: $v$/n goes to 0 as n approaches infinity. So $X_n$ can only converge to c in some sense. but not to a non-degenerate normal distribution.

Comment: You cannot use $n$ in the limit since $n$ goes to $\infty$.

Answer (score 7):

No, it doesn't make much sense to say that
$$X_n \overset{d}{\to} N\left(c, \frac{v}{n}\right)\,.$$
The main reason is because the $\overset{d}{\to}$ is as $n\to \infty$, and if $n\to \infty$ in the limit, then on the right hand side $v/n$ makes no sense. Instead, an appropriate consequence for the CLT is the use of the "approximately distributed" notation which is usually "$\approx$". So,

$$X_n \approx N\left(c, \frac{v}{n}\right)\,. $$

Comment: +1 though some people object to $\approx$ for "approximately distributed"  as they think it is too close to using $=$ for "exactly distributed"

Comment: @Henry hmm yes. What do they recommend to use for "approximately distributed" then?

Comment: Somewhat like $\stackrel{D}{\approx}$?

Comment: Writing  "approximately distributed as" can work. Wikipedia's article on the [central limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem#Relation_to_the_law_of_large_numbers) tends to spell it out except for a couple of cases of $\approx$ preceded by a suggestion such usage is informal

Comment: And would it be ok to say that $X_n$ has asymptotic variance equal to $\frac{v}{n}$ if $X_n$ is approximately distributed as in your answer?

Comment: @nsimplex Technically $X_n$ has asymptotic variance 0. If samples are iid, $X_n$ should have *exact* variance $v/n$.